# Natbib error. Not \author given

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, jabref

I'm using `natbib` and `JabRef` to produce the bibligraphy for my project.

It was working correctly, but after trying to enter the reference of a software (`@software{,` ), it started to give me this error, which has persisted, in which the references appear numerically.

```
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
```

I fixed the bib file, as JabRef informed me that some authors were not spelled correctly, however it did not solve the problem.

The only thing I can think of is that in the name of the journal in some cases the message "abbreviation dettected" appears, since the diminutive of the journal matches the full name (`Cell` = `Cell`), but I don't know how to solve this, or if this is what is producing the error.

An example of a `software` bib entry:

```
@software{hadoop,
  author = {{Apache Software Foundation}},
  title = {Hadoop},
  url = {https://hadoop.apache.org},
  version = {0.20.2},
  date = {2010-02-19},
}
```

However, I don't have any software entry in my bib file right now, but the error keeps appearing.

I'm using:

```
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Below I list all the packages I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Escribir en castellano.
\usepackage{mathptmx }%Adobe Times Roman (or equivalent) as default font
\usepackage{titlesec} %Selection from various title styles
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} %control de tamaño de papel y márgenes
\usepackage{graphicx} %para poder incluir figuras 
\usepackage{siunitx} %para notación científica
\usepackage{float} %complemento para figura
\usepackage{import} %para poder dividir el texto en varios archivos
\usepackage{natbib} %para la bibliografía
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing %Control del espacio entre lineas
\usepackage{xcolor} %Para cambiar el color de texto
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} %Diagrama de Gantt
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
```

Comment: Can you post  an example of the bibliography with a `@software bib entry?

Comment: Already did @Guido

Comment: @roybatty What `\bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: @egreg I'm using apalike

Comment: The problem is probably that (most if not all) BibTeX styles cannot deal with a `date` field. The publication year must be given in the `year` field (the `month` field can be used to specify the month of publication, there is in general no `day` field). Since your style does not know `date`, it is simply ignored. But if there is no year, `natbib` can't do all of its magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues at play here.

Firstly, as mentioned in [Christoph S](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95109/christoph-s)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599220/35864), your bibliography style `apalike` does not technically know the `@software` entry type. It will therefore fall back to `@misc`. (`biblatex` styles generally know `@software` since it is part of the standard data model there.) This need not be a big deal. You could switch to `@misc` to avoid a warning, or you could stick to `@software` for the more semantic name.

Secondly and more importantly, `apalike` (and I believe it is the same for all BibTeX styles) does not know the `date` field (again `date` is something from the `biblatex` world). BibTeX styles generally only have `year` and `month` fields. The following will compile

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{hadoop,
  author  = {{Apache Software Foundation}},
  title   = {Hadoop},
  url     = {https://hadoop.apache.org},
  version = {0.20.2},
  year    = {2010},
  month   = feb,
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \citep{hadoop}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Thirdly, and this is probably a minor point, `apalike` was not designed specifically to be used with `natbib`. That's why there not being a `year` causes an error. If you use a style from the `natbib` bundle like `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` a missing year does not cause errors. In general you can use `apalike` and `natbib` together and usually you get good results, but this is one of the cases where there is a bit of an issue.

Note that neither of the styles suggested here knows the `version` field, so it will be ignored. If you want/have to stick to BibTeX, you may have to play around with the available fields like `howpublished` etc. to get good output for this entry.

Overall it looks like this entry was designed for `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Software` is from the biblatex [software package](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-software) which requires biblatex + biber as backend.

If you want to stick to BibTeX you need to change your bib entry to `@Misc`

Comment: `@software` is also a stock entry type in standard `biblatex` (see p. 13 of the `biblatex` documentation), `biblatex-software` is only needed for additional specialised software entry types and additional fields. All fields shown in the entry in the question will work absolutely fine with standard `biblatex`.